# Moving Icon Towards Right in Drawer Navigator Toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am editing Material UI's drawer navigator example code. I added a notification icon and a checkout icon with the Admin Panel typography within the toolbar.

The checkout icon is towards the right end but for some reason the notification icon is just stuck in the middle. How could I fix this?

Drawer.tsx:

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
    },
    appBar: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },

    panelheaderRight:{
        marginRight: 0,
        right: 0,
    },
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    content: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  }),
);

export default function PermanentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar className="toolbar-class">
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Admin Panel
          </Typography>
          <NotificationsIcon className='panelheaderRight'/>
          <ExitToAppIcon className='panelheaderRight'/>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
        anchor="left"
      >
        <div className='toolbar'/>
        <Divider />
        <List>
        {[{ text: 'Home', url: '/panel', icon: <HomeIcon/>}].map((item, index) => (
            <Link to={item.url} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
            <ListItem button key={item.text}>
              <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={item.text} />
            </ListItem>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />   
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also added this css code separately but it doesn't work.
Drawer.css:

```
.panelheaderRight{
    margin-right: 0;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
}
.toolbar-class{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css to the toolbar

```
.toolbar-class{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Comment: Should I add this where I have written: ```<div className={classes.toolbar} />```? I tried but that didn't work :(

Comment: Add it where you have written the styles for the toolbar ... also the reason why it doesnt work might be because the toolbar doesnt take the full width of the blue area
try also add width: 100% to the above snippet.

Comment: Could you see my updated qs? That's how the icons move if I follow your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you need an extra wrapper; watch this:

```css
.toolbar-class {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.toolbar-after {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar-class">
  <div>Admin panel</div>
  <div class="toolbar-after">
    <p class="item">bell</p>
    <p class="item">exit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want an extra wrapper you could use css grid

```css
.toolbar-class {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar-class">
  <div>Admin panel</div>
    <p class="item">bell</p>
    <p class="item">exit</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In that case, the ADMIN  PANEL typography also goes to the right end.